# Printing the array through each pass

Tags: java

My code works fine, but I'm stuck in one part. I want to be able to print every swap, instead of printing the final sorting. Can someone help me ?

```
public class SelectionSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int []numbers = {10,5,7,9,1,0,4,6,11,14};
         numSort(numbers);
         printArray(numbers);
    }
    public static int[] numSort(int[] A) {
        for (int i = 0; i <A.length -1 ; i++ ) {
            for (int j=0; j<A.length-1-i; j++ ) {
                if(A[j] > A [j+1]) {
                    int temp = A[j+1];
                    A[j+1] = A[j];
                    A[j]=temp;
                }

            }
        }
        return A;
    }
     public static void printArray(int[] A) {
        for (int i = 0; i<A.length; i++ ) {
            System.out.println(A[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: I thought your code works fine?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do in order to print the array after each swap is call the `printArray()` method after each swap, like so:

```
public static int[] numSort(int[] A) {
    for (int i = 0; i <A.length -1 ; i++ ) {
        for (int j=0; j<A.length-1-i; j++ ) {
            if(A[j] > A [j+1]) {
                int temp = A[j+1];
                A[j+1] = A[j];
                A[j]=temp;
                printArray(A);
            }
        }
    }
    return A;
}
```

However, your print method makes it such that it will be hard to tell between successive arrays, because you print each number on a new line. To fix this, you can simply use the native `.toString()` method, or you can print all of the values on the same line, seperated by spaces or commas, and use `\n` or an empty `System.out.println()` at the end to move to the next line.

Comment: I'm editing the post to solve a potential issue the asker might have with my solution

Comment: Thanks, I have one small problem, the numers print vertically instead of horizantally. How to a fix that

Comment: That's because you make a new line for each number in your array in your print method. Read the bottom of my answer for the solution.